# Flutter : IOS to IOS Broadcast Beacon not working

Tags: ios, flutter, ibeacon, beacon

I'm currently building an app that turns my device into a Beacon while simultaneously scanning for other Beacons.
So I can keep track of beacons that I had come in contact with.

---

**Problem**

Current I've tested this code in the following Scenarios:

1. Android TO Android - Broadcasting & Scanning - Working well
2. Android To IOS - BroadCasting & Scanning Both ways - Working well
3. IOS to IOS - Not Working (When I broadcast UUID from IOS Device, I can see UUID in Android device but I can't see UUID in any IOS device.)

---

- I installed this piece of code in 4 devices (2 Android & 2 IOS). Now all 4 devices are broadcasting different UUID's and at the same time listening.
- In Android Devices, I see 1 UUID of another Android Device and 2 UUID's of IOS Devices
- In IOS Devices, I see 2 Android UUID's but I cannot see another IOS Device UUID.

**This is very strange, and I need help to solve this, please!**

---

I've currently implemented 2 packages to achieve this functionality :

**(1) For broadcast**

> beacon_broadcast: https://pub.dev/packages/beacon_broadcast
>   version : 0.2.1

**(2) For scan other beacons**

> flutter_blue: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue
>   version : 0.6.3+1

---

**These are some glimpse of my code**

**(1) For Broadcasting**

```
String UUID = 'DYNAMIC_UUID_FOR_EACH_DEVICE';
static const MAJOR_ID = 1;
static const MINOR_ID = 30;
static const TRANSMISSION_POWER = -59;
static const IDENTIFIER = 'com.example.myDeviceRegion';
static const LAYOUT = 'm:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24';
static const MANUFACTURER_ID = 0x004c;

BeaconBroadcast beaconBroadcast = BeaconBroadcast();
beaconBroadcast
   .setUUID(UUID)
   .setMajorId(MAJOR_ID)
   .setMinorId(MINOR_ID)
   .setTransmissionPower(TRANSMISSION_POWER)
   .setIdentifier(IDENTIFIER)
   .setLayout(LAYOUT)
   .setManufacturerId(MANUFACTURER_ID);
   .start();
```

**(2) For Scanning**

```
FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 30));
flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((List<ScanResult> results) {
  print('scanningListen...');
  for (ScanResult result in results) {
      result.advertisementData.manufacturerData.forEach((item, hexcodeAsArray) => {
         print("calculated UUID String : " + calculateHexFromArray(v));
         _addToScanResult(calculateHexFromArray(v));
      });
  }
}
String calculateHexFromArray(decimalArray) {
  String uuid = '';
  decimalArray.forEach((i) => {uuid += i.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')});
  String uuid1 = uuid.substring(4, uuid.length - 12);
  return uuid1.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use FlutterBlue to detect iBeacon packets on iOS.

Why?  FlutterBlue uses raw bluetooth scanning to detect beacons, which under the hood means using the native CoreBluetooth scanning APIs on iOS.  Apple blocks CoreBluetooth APIs from reading the raw bytes of any bluetooth advertisement decodable as an iBeacon advertisement.  While this may sound crazy, it is likely motivated by misguided security concerns by Apple.  Read more in my blog post here: [CoreBluetooth Doesn't Let You See iBeacons](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons)

Two options to fix this:

1. Switch to using the AltBeacon format.  Simply change `LAYOUT = 'm:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25';` and `MANUFACTURER_ID = 0x0118;`

   This will work, but has the disadvantage of the advertisement only being detectable on iOS in the foreground.
2. Switch to using a different detection library on iOS that uses CoreLocation (the only API allowed to detect iBeacon on iOS) instead of CoreBluetooth.  That means giving up FlutterBlue in favor of [FlutterBeacon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon) or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I will try above solutions and let you know. @davidgyoung

Comment: Hello @davidgyoung, I had already tried option 1 but It was not working now I tried option 2 as per your suggestion and I installed flutter_becaon plugin. IOS is very well detecting Only If I broadcast the same UUID, In my case UUID will be different and I want to fetch them 
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Hi David I have similar problem too why on ios I can't detect and I would like to scan based on range only is it possible?

Comment: @newbie, please post a new question and I'll be glad to answer.

Comment: @davidgyoung as requested I have posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442488/flutter-ios-beacon-not-able-to-scan-with-region-and-uuid-settings. Thank you.

Comment: @davidgyoung I'm using the library you suggested FlutterBeacon. I'm also advertising as iBeacon as you suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/60892464/3455666.  Everything is just working fine except that beacon ranging not working in background for android 8+. Will be helpful if you could please check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62232482/3455666 and suggest some workaround. Thanks.