# Flutter IOS beacon not able to scan with Region and UUID settings

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this problem is that in flutter I notice there is not able to operate or use the traditional bluetooth as there is no any library supporting it. I have tested flutter_blue-master etc. So then I saw that it can behave as beacon. So I have used the codes below. For android I just set

```
Region(
      identifier: 'com.example.myDeviceRegion',)); its able to work. So the same I set in IOS its not able to work? So what is best workaround for blueetooth in flutter? I am using this package flutter_beacon. For the beacon broadcasting I am using this package beacon_broadcast.

initScanBeacon() async {
    await flutterBeacon.initializeScanning;
    await checkAllRequirements();
    if (!authorizationStatusOk ||
        !locationServiceEnabled ||
        !bluetoothEnabled) {
      print('RETURNED, authorizationStatusOk=$authorizationStatusOk, '
          'locationServiceEnabled=$locationServiceEnabled, '
          'bluetoothEnabled=$bluetoothEnabled');
      return;
    }
    /*final regions = <Region>[
      Region(
        identifier: 'com.example.myDeviceRegion',       
      ),
    ];*/
    final regions = <Region>[];
    regions.add(Region(
      identifier: 'com.example.myDeviceRegion',
      minor: 100,
      major: 1));

    if (_streamRanging != null) {
      if (_streamRanging.isPaused) {
        _streamRanging.resume();
        return;
      }
    }

    _streamRanging =
        flutterBeacon.monitoring(regions).listen((MonitoringResult result) {
      print(result);
      if (result != null && mounted) {
        print("GOT RESTULT READY");
        setState(() {
          //_regionBeacons[result.region] = result.region;
          _beacons.clear();
          print("List value is json"+result.toJson.toString());
          _regionBeacons.values.forEach((list) {
            print("List value is");
            _beacons.addAll(list);
            print("after Beacon size now is "+_beacons.length.toString());
          });
          //_beacons.sort(_compareParameters);
          print("Beacon size now is "+_beacons.length.toString());
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Make sure your Region definition has a proximityUUID value.  I am surprised that it works even on Android without this.  On iOS it certainly won't work at all -- iOS requires a beacon proximityUUID be specified up front in order to detect.  The value you give for the prximityUUID must exactly match what your beacon is advertising or you won't see it.
- Make sure you have gone through all the iOS setup steps here:  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon
- Be extra sure that you have granted location permission to your iOS app.  You can go to Settings -> Your App Name to check if location permission is granted.
- Make sure bluetooth is enabled in settings for the phone
- Make sure location is enabled in settings for the phone

Comment: so meaning that it can only read a specific uuid set beacon is it? So it can't read any beacon randomly? My problem actually I want to detect those phone with specified uuid via Bluetooth how to achieve that via flutter?

Comment: No, iOS does not let you see any iBeacon transmission.  You must know the UUID up front.  See here http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons

Comment: so in this case what is the best way I can build in flutter something like these contact tracing via Bluetooth? Any suggestion for that

Comment: You can use a single UUID for all iBeacon transmissions and simply vary the major and minor value on each installation.  Since a major has 16 bits and minor has 16 bits, this gives you 2^32 combinations or over 4 billion.  This is enough to cover nearly as many people as there are in the world.

Comment: I tried doing that but on ios it seems not working either. It's can't scan beacon from android. But android can scan ios?

Comment: Use a second Android phone and an off the shelf detector like BeaconScope to verify your Android transmission works as you think.

Comment: @davidgyoung Hi David, I tried flutter_beacon and I am able to scan ios-ios. But the ios is unable to detect for Android. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: @davidgyoung so what exactly settings you suggest weird now its not working neither from ios or android I cant detect ? What should I do the correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon

There's an update on GitHub but was yet to push to pub.dev previously.
Do update to 0.5.0.

Always check pub.dev for updates. or github reported issues.