# Flutter ranging beacons in background - Android 8.0

Tags: android, flutter, background, beacon

I'm using [flutter_beacon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon) for detecting iBeacons in one of my flutter project. Its working fine in foreground and in background for android version below 8. But its not detecting beacons in background for android version 8 and above.

As per [background location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits): Android 8.0 (API level 26) limits how frequently background apps can retrieve the user's current location. Apps can receive location updates only a few times each hour.

I've also reported an issue to github with the example code [here](https://github.com/alann-maulana/flutter_beacon/issues/61)

Is there any extra code I have to write in order to make android device with version 8+ be able to detect beacons in background ?

Comment: This is not a limitation of Flutter, but of the Android APIs. I'm afraid it is by design, because of privacy and battery.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is Restricted According to this : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

BUT, according to the same doc, you Can do what you need to do only if your app has one of these,

1. It has a foreground service.
2. Input method editor (IME)
3. Wallpaper service
4. Notification listener
5. Voice or text service

you can go with 1st or 3rd one but it requires some platform specific coding.

Comment: 'Foreground Services' is the one I would like to try, but I've no idea android native side code. Please help @Srilal

Comment: @iAkshay I would recommend using a permanent notification to keep the foreground service alive. read more https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: also for the permenent notification you can use the flutter local notfications plugin. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications .

Comment: I guess foreground service shows notification permanently. I'm already using flutter local notification plugin for showing notification when beacon is detected. Could you please post some example code, that will be helpful. Thanks.